# How many ways to choose $ i,j,k,l$ from $1,\ldots, n$ such that $i<j$ and $k<l$

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to work my way through the proof of [Lemma 2 in Broder, A., & Karlin, A. R. (1990). Multilevel Adaptive Hashing. SODA 90](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320181) in order to generalise it as explained in a [related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57332/mean-and-variance-of-number-of-buckets-of-length-i-in-hashing-with-chaining).

I am stuck at the "Summing over all possible choices" part of the proof. You do not need to read the paper or the lemma or the proof to understand and/or answer this question; I'll abstract the part I do not understand into a self-contained question.

Fix a positive integer $n\geqslant 4$. Then let $i, j, k, l$ be four integers such that $1\leqslant i < j \leqslant n$ and $1\leqslant k < l \leqslant n$. How many ways (order matters) to choose $i, j, k, l$ if

1. $\{i, j, k, l\}$ contains $4$ distinct elements
2. $\{i, j, k, l\}$ contains $3$ distinct elements
3. $\{i, j, k, l\}$ contains $2$ distinct elements

The answer the paper seems to provide is $6\binom{n}{4}$, $6\binom{n}{3}$, and $\binom{n}{2}$, respectively. I do not understand where these come from. [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) do not apply, and permutations and combinations do not apply either. I have considered integer compositions and partitions but I came empty handed.

Thank you,

**UPDATE:** The general case solution is given in [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1781619/558)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fourth case is the easiest to see. There are $\binom{n}2$ $2$-element subsets of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Say that $\{a,b\}$ is such a subset, with $a<b$. Then the only way to draw a $4$-tuple $\langle i,j,k,\ell\rangle$ from $[n]$ so that $i<j$, $k<\ell$, and $\{i,j,k,\ell\}=\{a,b\}$ is to draw $\langle a,b,a,b\rangle$. Thus, each of the $\binom{n}2$ $2$-element subset of $[n]$ gives rise to exactly one acceptable sequence of draws, and there are therefore $\binom{n}2$ such sequences with $2$ distinct members.

The first case isn’t too bad. There are $\binom{n}4$ ways to choose $4$ elements of the set $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Consider a $4$-element subset of $[n]$. There are $4!$ possible orders in which it could be drawn, one for each of its permutations. Let $p_1p_2p_3p_4$ be a generic permutation of the elements. Since the map $p_1p_2p_3p_4\mapsto p_2p_1p_3p_4$ is a bijection, exactly half of the $4!$ permutations have $p_1<p_2$. Similarly, exactly half of those $12$ have $p_3<p_4$. Thus, each $4$-element subset of $[n]$ can be chosen in $6$ acceptable orders, and there are therefore $6\binom{n}4$ acceptable draws with $4$ distinct members.

The second case is the trickiest. There are of course $\binom{n}3$ possible $3$-element subsets of $[n]$. Let $\{a,b,c\}$ be such a subset, with $a<b<c$. The numbers drawn can then be the members of any of the [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) $\{\!\{a,a,b,c\}\!\},\{\!\{a,b,b,c\}\!\}$, or $\{\!\{a,b,c,c\}\!\}$, so we now have $3\binom{n}3$ possible multisets of numbers drawn. How many sequences are acceptable? The acceptable sequences from $\{\!\{a,a,b,c\}\!\}$ are $\langle a,b,a,c\rangle$ and $\langle a,c,a,b\rangle$; those from $\{\!\{a,b,b,c\}\!\}$ are $\langle a,b,b,c\rangle$ and $\langle b,c,a,b\rangle$, and those from $\{\!\{a,b,c,c\}\!\}$ are $\langle a,c,b,c\rangle$ and $\langle b,c,a,c\rangle$. That is, each of the multisets can be acceptably ordered in $2$ ways, so there are $2\cdot3\binom{n}3=6\binom{n}3$ acceptable draws with $3$ distinct elements.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where $\{i, j, k, l\}$ contains four distinct elements,
choose four distinct numbers from the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$,
and then choose two of those numbers to be $i$ and $j$.
The other two numbers must be $k$ and $l$.
Since $i < j$ and $k < l$, this uniquely determines which of the first
two numbers is $i$ and which is $j$, similarly with $k$ and $l$.
Moreover, there is only one way to get any particular set of 
$\{i, j, k, l\}$ in this way that meets the constraints.

There are $\binom64$ ways to choose the four numbers, and 
$\binom42 = 6$ ways to choose two numbers out of the four,
so that makes $6\binom64$ altogether.

In the case where $\{i, j, k, l\}$ contains three distinct elements,
the six possible orderings are 
$i < j = k < l$,
$k < l = i < j$,
$i < k < j = l$,
$k < i < j = l$,
$i = k < j < l$, and
$i = k < l < j$.
Choose one of those orderings, and then choose three distinct elements
from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ to be the three values in the ordering.
This uniquely determines $i, j, k,$ and $l$.

Since there are $6$ orderings and $\binom63$ ways to choose the values
to fill them, we have $6 \binom63$ altogether.

For two distinct values, we must have
$i = k < j = l$.
So simply choose two distinct numbers from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$;
the smaller one is $i$.
There are $\binom62$ ways to choose the pair of numbers, and that's that.

Comment: @M.Alaggan Yes, that was a typo. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

*For $1.$*
First count the possibilities of extracting the pair $\{i,j\}$ then, from the remaining numbers the possibilities of extracting the pair $\{k, l\}$
so the number of ways is $\binom{n}{2} \binom{n-2}{2} = 6\binom{n}{4}$.

Another idea: a subset of $4$ elements from $1,..,n$ generates exactly $6$ ways of choosing $\{i,j,k,l\}$ so the number of ways is $6\binom{n}{4}$

Similar for $2.$ and $3.$

**UPDATE**

$\binom{n}{2}=\frac {n(n -1)} 2$

$\binom{n-2}{2}=\frac {(n-2)(n -3)} 2$

$6\binom{n}{4}=6 \frac {n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)} {4!} \  = \frac {n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)} 4$

Comment: How is $\binom{n}{2} \binom{n-2}{2} = 6\binom{n}{4}$? You lost me there.

Comment: @M.Alaggan See my updated response.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Suppose we have been given a comma seperated string of digits from $1$ to $n$ i.e. $n$ integers .Number of ways to choose $4$ different integers from that list of $n$ integers is $^nC_4$.Now we have to assign these four numbers to i,j, k & l. Suppose if first one is $i$ then we have $3$ choices for $j$ ;if second one is $i$ then we have two choices for $j$ and if third one is $i$ then only the fourth one can be $j$ so there are 6 choices for assignment so in total it is $$6 \times {n \choose 4}$$
The same logic is for other two

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the general case follows.

Let $T(n,k):=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}$ as defined in OEIS sequence [A063007](https://oeis.org/A063007).

Then there is $$T(t, q-t) \binom{n}{q} = \binom{t}{q-t}\binom{q}{q-t} \binom{n}{q}$$ ways to choose $\{i_1,\ldots,i_t, j_1,\ldots, j_t \}$ such that

1. $\{i_1,\ldots,i_t, j_1,\ldots, j_t \}$ containing $t\leqslant q \leqslant 2t$ distinct elements, and
2. $i_1<\cdots<i_t$, and
3. $j_1<\cdots<j_t$.

I have no proof of this fact. I just wrote a [small program](https://gist.github.com/malaggan/4e65d4b8b6af1cb97f4f0ce43767d6a2) to count the ways for $t\in\{2,\ldots,5\}$ then I looked up the resulting sequence on OEIS. The program's idea was inspired by Brian M. Scott's answer.